# half-sibling's child listed as 1st/2nd cousin

Tags: dna

A child of a half-sibling has been determined to be a 1st or 2nd cousin; and the explanation is that variability to four degrees. Is it possible that the half-sibling status with his mother creates some sort of anomaly?

Answer (score 4):

This is completely normal.

The relationship predictions on the various DNA test sites are based on how much DNA you and your match share, and each potential relationship actually has a range for how much DNA will be shared. A really good overview of this is thednageek's blog post [The Limits of Predicting Relationships Using DNA](http://thednageek.com/the-limits-of-predicting-relationships-using-dna/).

For your specific case, check out the green chart in that blog post. Group C on that chart is what you want to look at; you'll notice that Group C includes both first cousin and half-nephew.

Another resource to check out is Blaine Bettinger's [Shared cM Project](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4). At the linked site, you can input the amount of shared DNA (either cM or percentage), and you'll be shown all the possible relationships. It will also give you a table of likelihoods for various potential relationships.